# JavaScript search in many txt files

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search bar in HTML page and I have many text files and I want to do a search with Javascript to find String in all the text file. I want to know if its possible to do it with Javascript. I can do it search in one text but not many. Here is search script and the HTML.

```js
function readTextFile(file,str)
{
 var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
 rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
 {
  
  if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
  {
   if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
   {
    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
    if(allText.search(str) != -1){
     alert("exist");
     alert(location.pathname);
    }else{
     alert("not exist");
    }
   }
  }
 }
 rawFile.send(null); 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="search" onsubmit="return readTextFile('All-html.txt',this.string.value);">
   <input name="string" onchange="n = 0;">
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
  </form>
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: hi i didn't know what is jsfiddle before !! thanks for this information :)
here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/YSSR/8gwbye3j/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/YSSR/bytvchwf/#&togetherjs=xjDfmGB2i2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function works (`readTextFile(file,str)`), I would write a new function that iterates over the files list and call `readTextFile` for each file. Also return true/false if the str was found.

```
function searchAllfiles(str){
    var files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"];
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
        found = readTextFile(filename, str);
        if (found){
            alert(str + " was found in " + filename);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

You can't get the files list from the server using only JS.

1 Option is to keep track on the clients side of the files the user adds dynamically 
Second option is to pass the list from the server. Maybe you can maintain the files list inside 1 file and get the paths by reading it or build a service that will return the files list and then call this service with an Ajax call via JS.

Comment: thanks  @Itay Gal good idea!! but i can't make files in a table, i have to charge them dynamicly because text file change

Comment: This is only an example. I created an array with files to iterate, you need to replace it with your files list.

Comment: yeah i see !! but i have a lot of text file in a folder, i can't make them in array, because the user can add some text file later, so i want to open all the text files and make a search
folder of text file is dynamic . if you see what i want to say

Comment: You can't get the files list from the server using only JS. You can keep track on the clients side of the files the user adds dynamically or pass the list from the server. Maybe you can maintain the files list inside 1 file and get the paths by reading it.